# Парсер на bs4. Не могу достать span с класса а

Tags: html, python, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def get_html():
    r = requests.get('https://prom.ua/Sportivnye-sumki') #Менять ссылку тут
    return r.text


soup = BeautifulSoup(get_html() , 'html.parser')
content = soup.find('div', class_='x-catalog__content-line')
right_col = content.find('div', class_='x-catalog-gallery')
news_list = right_col.find_all('div', class_='x-gallery-tile js-gallery-tile js-productad')
last_try = content.find_all('div', class_='x-gallery-tile__content')
print(last_try)
art_list = [] #Лист со статьями
i=0
for article in last_try:
    name = article.find('a', class_='x-gallery-tile__name')['span itemprop']

    price = article.find('div', class_='x-gallery-tile__price')['data-qaprice']
    link = article.find('a', class_='x-gallery-tile__name')['href']
    art_list.append([link,price,name])
print(art_list)
```

А проблема собственно заключается вот в чем:
все в коде работало до добавления строки с названием товара 'name'. 
После этого начал ловить ошибку

KeyError: 'span itemprop'

я  вроде бы понимаю на что она указывает. Но как тогда достать название товара? запечатанное в 'span'?
Это подкласс получается? или я что-то не так понимаю)

```
</div><a class="x-gallery-tile__name" data-qaid="product_name" href="https://my.prom.ua/remote/context_ads/click_ad_v2?token=v2%3AjWH6NHZy2pv_XPOaPBL0PUmqsDbS5hE3PtFj-ayNQh73LMUJgVk1S_1RjoldWqlSjZh4lxim9TMx9vkRKNZC&amp;campaign_id=643776&amp;product_id=724626250&amp;source=prom%3Acatalog&amp;variant=&amp;locale=ru&amp;prices_param=&amp;category_ids=380630" itemprop="url" rel="" target="_self"><span itemprop="name">Спортивная сумка Tiger</span></a></div>]
```

Мой первый вопрос на сервисе. Не нужно кидаться камнями)
С радостью приму любую помощь ,будь то ссылка на обьяснение этих приколов или исправление строчки кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`span` это уже другой тег. Его также надо найти, как вы искали `a` и `div`'ы.

```
name = article.find('span', { 'itemprop' : 'name'}).text
```

Первая запись в `art_list` у меня получилась такая:

```
#['https://my.prom.ua/remote/context_ads/click_ad_v2?token=v2%3Aoy0MVCv7RAFLJSWUvHX9A76ChOns4-5xTjrUFqE_uVPBPFTxQ42EzTypMx0fcq5reeeYfFUw-La4A1D1VejS&campaign_id=281004&product_id=530423624&source=prom%3Acatalog&variant=&locale=ru&prices_param=&category_ids=380630', '245.00000', 'Спортивная сумка в стиле Nike черная экокожа']
```